# How to get Typegen to use the Custom RPC Runtime

Tags: substrate-node, substrate-front-end, typegen

We have implemented custom template pallet rpc methods and they are visible when doing a call to the node on `rpc.methods`
we get

```
template_sum5
template_sumAndStore
```

however typegen is not adding them...

is it possible to get the polkadotJs typegen to add these to its augement api rpc file or some other way to use the types from rust?